# Hi everybody, I am trying to install gromacs 5.1.4

Tags: software-installation

I am a new user in Ubuntu and I am trying to install gromacs 5.1.4 in it, but in the last steps of installation I get an error mentioning that network is unreachable. I also add the code here in case it might come handy.

```
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=ON
-- No compatible CUDA toolkit found (v4.0+), disabling native GPU acceleration
-- The GROMACS-managed build of FFTW 3 will configure with the following optimizations: --enable-sse2;--enable-avx
Downloading: http://gerrit.gromacs.org/download/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz
-- [download 0% complete]
-- [download 100% complete]
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:57 (message):
error: downloading
'http://gerrit.gromacs.org/download/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz' failed

status_code: 7
status_string: "Couldn't connect to server"
log: Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 41173 (#0)
GET http://gerrit.gromacs.org/download/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz
HTTP/1.1
Host: gerrit.gromacs.org
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 334
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 06:53:35 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=58
Location:
ftp://ftp.gromacs.org/regressiontests/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)


Ignoring the response-body
[334 bytes data]
Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
Issue another request to this URL:
'ftp://ftp.gromacs.org/regressiontests/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz'
    Trying 130.237.25.126...
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
connect to 130.237.25.126 port 21 failed: Connection refused
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
    Trying 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed...
Immediate connect fail for 2001:6b0:1:1190:5054:ff:fe2f:daed: Network is unreachable
Failed to connect to ftp.gromacs.org port 21: Connection refused

Closing connection 1

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mahsheed/Downloads/gromacs-5.1.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mahsheed/Downloads/gromacs-5.1.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem with network connection from server to ftp.gromacs.org. Are you able to ping to this location?

```
ping ftp.gromacs.org
```

If yes, can you see if wget is fetching this file?

```
wget ftp://ftp.gromacs.org/regressiontests/regressiontests-5.1.4.tar.gz
```

You can also try to add an entry to the top of /etc/resolv.conf file and try again.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If none of this works, I guess there is a firewall which is blocking connections.

Comment: many thanks for your guidance. However, I'm afraid that none of these commands worked. So, I guess as you said there might be the firewall problem. If it's true, what should I do to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems downloading via wget. So I downloaded the packages with a browser.

It just solved my problem for the time being.